# Screen flickering problem in 16.04

Tags: screen, flicker

i upgraded 14.04 ubuntu to 16.04, after updating softwares in 16.04 my desktop screen flickers when i place mouse pointer in the launcher pad.
how can i solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This is [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594) (#1735594) that was reported December 1, 2017. Numerous bug reports have been filed, but marked as duplicates.

According to a comment on bug [#1741447](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1741447/comments/39), this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/) works, which many say fixed the issue. The main bug report also makes mention of this fix in reference to bug #1741447. Users can update their system with unsupported packages from this untrusted PPA by adding `ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa` to their system's Software Sources.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update
```

This solution works for me, and is probably going to become the official fix, or will be incorporated into an update, if it hasn't already. More information can be found in the given links. Be sure to restart your computer after this is installed.

If you are affected, let them know by marking you are affected at the [main bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1735594).

Also make sure you keep up with all the latest updates, especially if you are uncertain about the above solution or if it did not work for you.

Comment: still it is there. not fixed. could you tell me easy way to fix it

Comment: @piruthivi did you restart your computer are installing this update? Be sure to look at the this link for more information about getting this update: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/pkppa/

Comment: this is the output i got for doing                                                                                                 
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
praveen@ubuntu:~$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
Updating packages lists
PPA to be removed: paulo-miguel-dias pkppa
Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: paulo-miguel-dias pkppa
praveen@ubuntu:~$

Comment: @piruthivi in the link, the instructions are located at the bottom of the page. Looks like you used the command to remove it instead of installing it.

Comment: You may need to add it manually in your update settings

Comment: i added these two commands only but these two didnt worked.
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:paulo-miguel-dias/pkppa
sudo apt-get update

Comment: today(jan 17th 2018) i updated the upgrades through terminal, its cleared today. now i can use launcher icon no any issue. thanks for your help also

Comment: @piruthivi If my answer worked for you, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer.